# Using left join and distinct sums incorrect values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT [sb].[UserId]) AS NumberOfCustomers, 
    SUM([sb].[ProbabilityAlive]) AS ProbabilityAlive
FROM
    sb  
WHERE  
    sb.[Date] = '03/11/2020 00:00:00' 
    AND sb.[ClientId] = '1112'
```

This query returns:

```
NumberOfCustomers: 50280
ProbabilityAlive: 26107.6830
```

I recently added another table, and when using left join or join I get incorrect sum for probability alive:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT [dbo].[sb].[UserId]) AS NumberOfCustomers, 
    SUM([dbo].[sb].[ProbabilityAlive]) AS ProbabilityAlive,
    SUM([dbo].[AdditionalClvData].[PeakClv]) AS PeakClv
FROM
    sb  
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[AdditionalClvData] ON [dbo].[AdditionalClvData].UserId = [dbo].[sb].UserId  
 WHERE  
     sb.[CalculationDate] = '03/11/2020 00:00:00' 
     AND sb[ClientId] = '2'
```

This query now returns this result:

```
NumberOfCustomers: 50280
ProbabilityAlive: 76949.2354
PeakClv: 44835004.95810
```

`ProbabilityAlive` is almost three times bigger. Shouldn't it get the same sum when using left join?

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the code is clearly SQL Server.  Also, sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Why did the numbers change? Because there is a 1:M relationship between the tables. So no, your expectation is not correct. Sum/count first, then join.

Comment: If you remove the distinct and aggregation functions, you'll probably see that your outer join isn't doing what you _think_ it's doing. I'd make sure your query returns the records you want, before aggregating. Distinct may give you a warm fuzzy feeling of having it right, but it can also hide "I'm retrieving every record in the table"

Comment: FYI 3 part naming for columns is due to be deprecated and should be avoided. Give your objects aliases and qualify your columns with those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend pre-aggregating in subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS NumberOfCustomers, 
    SUM(s.ProbabilityAlive) AS ProbabilityAlive,
    SUM(a.PeakClv) as PeakClv
FROM (
    SELECT [UserId], SUM([sb].[ProbabilityAlive]) AS ProbabilityAlive
    FROM sb  
    WHERE sb.[Date] = '20200311'
    GROUP BY [UserId]
) s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [UserId], SUM([PeakClv]) as PeakClv
    FROM [dbo].[AdditionalClvData]
    GROUP BY [UserId]
) a ON a.[UserId] = s.[UserId]
```